# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Oof, "is water ionic" returns http://www.pureionicwater.com before http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/why-isnt-water-an-ionic-compound

Comment: Haha, @GeoffHutchison that's definitely a miss!

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Wow! Ouch!

Comment: I think that was really the worst of the evaluation that I saw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to know whether s-p mixing will happen in heteronuclear molecules?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22114/how-to-know-whether-s-p-mixing-will-happen-in-heteronuclear-molecules)

**Net Score: 23** (Excellent: 25, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to check if azobisisobutyronitrile (AIBN) is still active?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20439/how-to-check-if-azobisisobutyronitrile-aibn-is-still-active)

**Net Score: 22** (Excellent: 23, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why is water "the universal" solvent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21898/why-is-water-the-universal-solvent)

**Net Score: 22** (Excellent: 22, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is the electronegativity of hydrogen 2.20?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/why-is-the-electronegativity-of-hydrogen-2-20)

**Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does radioactivity affect chemical reactions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/does-radioactivity-affect-chemical-reactions)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why isn't water an ionic compound?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/why-isnt-water-an-ionic-compound)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Why is it necessary to consider infinitesimal changes in p,V,T for H,U and G given that they're state functions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21737/why-is-it-necessary-to-consider-infinitesimal-changes-in-p-v-t-for-h-u-and-g-giv)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Can you have addition polymerisation with monomers other than alkenes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22403/can-you-have-addition-polymerisation-with-monomers-other-than-alkenes)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 19, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Molality of solution having more than one solute?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21881/molality-of-solution-having-more-than-one-solute)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Density of water and temperature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22024/density-of-water-and-temperature)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 13)

---

Comment: Not bad. Any kind of an official net score or should we just add them up?

Comment: @L.B. That was us giving the scores. Who *is* more authorized?! :) Excellent is +1 score, needs improvement is -1.